# How to draw arc in Fabric.js

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I'm working with Fabric.js and I would like to draw arcs on canvas. The closest shape I can find is the `Circle` shape. This, of course, only enables me to make a circle and nothing like an arc spanning 45° or 180°.

Is there a way to accomplish this with Fabric.js?  If not, is there a way I can get the underlying context and then create the arc and allow fabric to manage it? It is important that I retain the selection and scaling capabilities that Fabric.js offers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In latest version of FabricJS for circle were added `startAngle` and `endAngle` properties.
https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/pull/1675

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');

var circle = new fabric.Circle({
    radius: 20,
    left: 100,
    top: 100,
    angle: 45,
    startAngle: 0,
    endAngle: Math.PI,
    stroke: '#000',
    strokeWidth: 3,
    fill: ''
});
```

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/mmeqec89/

Comment: This no longer works